# Remove the delay between this hover and showing of gif animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/mrvyw1m3/

I use css "background" to clip a background GIF to some text. Because the GIF has to be loaded at every hover (because otherwise it wouldnt start from beginning), i put a random string at the end of the URL. But now it creates a slight delay before the GIF shows and for a few miliseconds or seconds (depends on the download speed), you cant see the text.

Is there a way to make this technique possible but without the text dissappearing before the GIF shows?

```
$(".navMenu2 li").mouseenter(function() {
  var n = Date.now();
  // or   var n = Math.random();
  $(this).css({
    background: "linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(https://media.giphy.com/media/l2QDSTa6UcsRRSM5a/giphy.gif?ver=" + n + ") center",
    webkitTextFillColor: 'transparent',
    webkitBackgroundClip: 'text'
  });
});

$(".navMenu2 li").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css({
    background: "",
    webkitTextFillColor: '',
    webkitBackgroundClip: ''
  });
});
```

Comment: In my experience, animated gifs don't need cache-busting to force them to restart. Just reuse exactly the same url.

Comment: I tried that, but it just doesnt work:/ https://jsfiddle.net/mrvyw1m3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use text masking you will need to create a bit of text underneath that will never update, and then overlay your link on-top. You can also experiment with using ::before to do this using the same technique. You should be able to achieve this with pure css and :hover. However here is the first way.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snj91nkf/4/

```
<div class="navMenu2">
  <ul>
    <li class="liHver">
     <div class="link-cont">
        <a href="index.html"><span class="jap">作業</span><br>werk</a>
     </div>
     <div class="undertext">
       <span class="jap">作業</span><br>werk
     </div>
    </li> 
...
```

CSS Changes

```
 .link-cont,
 .undertext{
   color: #0e0e0e;
   font-size: 10rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   list-style-type: none;
   transition: background-image 2s ease;
 }

 .navMenu2 li{
  position: relative;
 }

 .link-cont {
   position:absolute;
   top: 2;

 }

.link-cont a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #0e0e0e;
 }
```

JS changes:

```
 $(".link-cont").mouseenter(function() {
   var n = Date.now();
   // or   var n = Math.random();
   $(this).css({
     background: "linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(https://media.giphy.com/media/l2QDSTa6UcsRRSM5a/giphy.gif?ver=" + n + ") center",
     webkitTextFillColor: 'transparent',
     webkitBackgroundClip: 'text'
   });
 });

 $(".link-cont").mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).css({
     background: "",
     webkitTextFillColor: '',
     webkitBackgroundClip: ''
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you alot! This is a very nice sollution. Dont know why i didnt think of this myself. But dont you need the JS to reload a different URL when using css :hover only?

Comment: No problem :) Yeah that is a good point if you want, to replay the gif you will need JS.